# Is there any way possible to create or delete Users in bulk using GRAPH API in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, createuser

I am trying to make a console app in C# through which I want to migrate more than 100000 users to Azure AD B2C.

We are using Graph API for this purpose.

My current approach creates a single user account per API call and **it takes more than 12 hours** to migrate around 50000 users.

To reduce the overall time **I want to send data in bulk instead of one by one** using the API. But, I am unable to find any solution for it.

Is there an API endpoint available for creating users in batch. Please help.

Also, If I want to delete these users in batch. Is it possible to do that?

Here are some Microsoft docs references which I have used for implementing my solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration?tabs=applications
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I want to do this in JAVA, I still do not understand how things are working here.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [JSON batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) to combine multiple requests in one HTTP call.

Here is an example:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch

{
    "requests": [{
            "id": "1",
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/users",
            "body": {
                "accountEnabled": true,
                "displayName": "allentest01",
                "mailNickname": "allentest01",
                "userPrincipalName": "allentest01@{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com",
                "passwordProfile": {
                    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
                    "password": "{password-value}"
                }
            },
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/users",
            "body": {
                "accountEnabled": true,
                "displayName": "allentest02",
                "mailNickname": "allentest02",
                "userPrincipalName": "allentest02@{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com",
                "passwordProfile": {
                    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
                    "password": "{password-value}"
                }
            },
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can also delete user with it. (use `DELETE` method)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add onto the Allen Wu Answer. This is how you would use it in c# for example.

```
string json = @"
{
    ""requests"": [{
            ""id"": ""1"",
            ""method"": ""POST"",
            ""url"": ""/users"",
            ""body"": {
                ""accountEnabled"": true,
                ""displayName"": ""zetawarsTest01"",
                ""mailNickname"": ""zetawarstest01"",
                ""userPrincipalName"": ""zetawarstest01@projecttarget.onmicrosoft.com"",
                ""passwordProfile"": {
                    ""forceChangePasswordNextSignIn"": false,
                    ""password"": ""zetawars123!@#""
                }
            },
            ""headers"": {
                ""Content-Type"": ""application/json""
            }
        }, {
            ""id"": ""2"",
            ""method"": ""POST"",
            ""url"": ""/users"",
            ""body"": {
                ""accountEnabled"": true,
                ""displayName"": ""zetawarsTest02"",
                ""mailNickname"": ""zetawarsTest02"",
                ""userPrincipalName"": ""zetawarsTest02@projecttarget.onmicrosoft.com"",
                ""passwordProfile"": {
                    ""forceChangePasswordNextSignIn"": false,
                    ""password"": ""zetawars123!@#""
                }
            },
            ""headers"": {
                ""Content-Type"": ""application/json""
            }
        }
        ]
    }
";
            //Credentials
            var tenantId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            var clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            var clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

            var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            //This to get the Access Token
            var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0")
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            var result = await confidentialClientApplication
                .AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" })
                .ExecuteAsync(); ;

             // This is to send Json Request using Client
            using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch"))
            {

                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                }


                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    string error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        if (response.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429)
                        {
                            // TBD: Add you error handling here
                        }

                        throw new Exception(error);
                    }
                    await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
```

I have read that there is limit of 20 users/request in batch. But i haven't tested that out yet.

Comment: Currently from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#batch-size-is-limited "JSON batch requests are currently limited to 20 individual requests."

Answer (score 0):

The approach of using JSON batching seems more reasonable but last time we had imported 160,000 users to Azure AD B2C via Graph API using Parallel.ForEach loop with MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 10. We were providing a batch of 40,000 users per run. It took 30 minutes to migrate 40,000 users batch.